# How do I merge these two javascript codes?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.formstack.com/forms/js.php?1134414-uqmj2UXxEw-v2">
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://www.formstack.com/forms/CampusEnterprises-chopped_greens_order_form__copy" title="Online Form">
Online Form - Chopped Greens Order Form - COPY
</a>
</noscript>
```

into the call of the isOpen() method at the end of the following javascript code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var theDate = new Date();
var dayOfWeek = theDate.getUTCDay();

// Returns true if the restaurant is open
function isOpen()
{
    //I'll fill this in later, for now, return true
    return true;
}
</script>

</head><body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
if(isOpen())
{
    //ADD CODE HERE
}
</script>
</body>
```

However, when I try to just copy and paste the two together it doesn't work.  I think it has something to do with nested  tags but I'm not sure

Comment: @SteveO'Connor - see the OP's last question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023231/whats-wrong-with-my-javascript-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write out the script into the document dynamically.

```
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
if(isOpen())
{
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.formstack.com/forms/js.php?1134414-uqmj2UXxEw-v2"></script>');
}
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="http://www.formstack.com/forms/CampusEnterprises-chopped_greens_order_form__copy" title="Online Form">
Online Form - Chopped Greens Order Form - COPY
</a>
</noscript>
</body>
```

As @Jared Farrish noted in the comments, you might as well use the `noscript` tag directly on the page.

Comment: Isn't it a little comical to `document.write('<noscript>')`?